# Data on organized crime

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to find data on organized crime such as Drug trade, criminal actors (mafia and criminal networks), and resilience. I am mainly focused on Europe, so it does not matter if the database is not worldwide.

Edit: I forgot to clarify that it needs to be country-level data as I am trying to study the effect of organized crime on the democracy of Eastern European countries

What organization or website would you suggest looking at? I have already checked [Global initiative](https://globalinitiative.net/analysis/ocindex-2021/), and World Bank

Comment: I'd take a look at Interpol: https://www.interpol.int/en/How-we-work/Databases

Comment: @RegressForward I checked Interpol also, but unfortunately, it does not have what I am looking for

Comment: https://havocscope.com/